# VLOOKUP and finding the column name in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a question regarding the application of vlookup function in Excel. If I want to return the first cell of a column that contains a certain value, how should I write the code? For example, if there is a value "2" contained in Column B, I want the result to be B1, and if there is such a value in Column C, I want to return C1. How am I supposed to write the code that fulfills my objective? Actually, it doesn't need to be vlookup if it's not possible to do so with vlookup. I need your help experts. Thank you.

Comment: You could try with hlookup

Comment: I'm sharing some Tutorial Links with you [Check this](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function),,  [Also](https://Support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but the hlookup method returns the number even though it should be a string. For example, I enumerated the mon-Friday in the first row, and I wrote the corresponding daily expenditure. I want the function to return the day with the highest expenditure. Thus, I wrote the following function: =HLOOKUP(MAX(B4:H4),B4:H4,1,0). However, it returns the index number of the corresponding column, not the cell value itself. Could I get to know the detour? Thank you.

Comment: Oh sorry, I figured it out. Thanks y'all for your assistance.

Comment: =INDEX($A$1:$H$3,1,MATCH(MAX(B4:H4),A4:H4,0))
I could do it in this way; may be I was thinking too much.

Comment: @SanghyeonKim,,, your question has title about VLOOKUP and now you are using another one HLOOKUP be sure all about your need !!